# Issues when Compiling & Building DPDK library (18.11) with USRP model N310, operating with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dpdk, usrp, uhd

Currently I am employed as an intern engineer at Viavi Solutions. I have been assigned to set-up a USRP based signal transmission/receiving framework, capable of driving multi-channel USRP from a server, in order to support 10 Gbps real-time streaming. This project is employing Ettus Research Universal Software Radio Peripheral (USRP) model N310. It is using two USRP N310 with 4 transmitters and 4 receivers.

It has been correctly installed, and is operating accordingly when performing network tests that employ the UDP protocol. However, there is an ongoing error when attempting to use the latest version of the DPDK library (DPDK-18.11). I have followed the instructions provided by Ettus Research and DPDK, which demonstrate how to correctly install and compile the newest version of the DPDK library (18.11). The following links are referenced below:

- https://kb.ettus.com/Getting_Started_with_DPDK_and_UHD
- https://doc.dpdk.org/guides-18.11/linux_gsg/build_dpdk.html

The error outputs the following messages:

"[WARNING] [DPDK] Detected use_dpdk argument, but DPDK support not built in."

"[WARNING] [MPMD] DPDK was requested but is not available, falling back to regular UDP"

I communicated and explained this problem with my supervisor, and he has encoutered the same issues. When using the latest DPDK library package (18.11) on the newer Ubuntu system, Viavi Solutions are not able to install and compile the DPDK libraries on the UHD building system. It is believed this might be because either un-recognised DPDK installation folder or DPDK/OS version is causing the UHD building system to not be able to recognise the installed and built DPDK files.

This is a rather important issue since Viavi Solution has bought and is in possession of many Ettus Research USRPs. Currently due to the issue explained above, when employing the newest OS version of Ubuntu and newest DPDK library package, the UHD cannot recognize the DPDK library, thus severely limiting Viavi Solutions on their possible network tests, since they can only employ the UDP communication protocol.

Currently, I am analyzing and going through the UHD source code, to try and find out if there is an error or some lines of code that need to be adapted or implemented to allow for the installation, compilation and build of the newest DPDK (18.11) library, with the newest Ubuntu OS.

I have contacted the Ettus Research support team but I am awaiting a reply. If anyone else has encountered this problem and has fixed it or has an idea on how to fix it, any help is appreciated!

Comment: @TomasVelso based on the gsg, it looks the DPDK Libraries are not used while building the application `but DPDK support not built in`. Checking the link to the documentation I am not able to find the steps to build with DPDK. Can you please go to the library folder `uhd/examples`, then clean, Install DPDK and rebuild the example with verbose option to cross check with DPDK is used or not?

Comment: How did you build UHD? From source? If so, CMake will tell you what's going on during its invokation. Depending on your UHD version, you might need a newer version of DPDK (e.g., recent version of UHD 4.1 need DPDK 19.11).